# Python Clock Project

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, clock, python-turtle

The clock hands won't clear after each movement and it creates a spiral effect.
I have tried moving update(), sleep(), and clear() around but nothing works.
I believe the problem is somewhere in the while true loop, but I could be wrong. The form will not post unless I add more words, so I am willing up this space

Here is the code:

```
import turtle
import time

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('beige')
window.tracer(0)


pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed(0)

# Draw the clock
pen.up()
pen.goto(0, 0)
pen.setheading(90)
pen.penup()
pen.goto(280, 0)
pen.pensize(10)
pen.pendown()
pen.begin_fill()
pen.fillcolor('white')
pen.circle(280)
pen.end_fill()
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()

# draw the minute hashes
for i in range(60):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.pensize(2)
    pen.speed(0)
    pen.forward(250)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.forward(20)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.right(6)

# draw the hour hashes
for p in range(12):
    turtle.speed(0)
    pen.forward(240)
    pen.pensize(5)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.forward(30)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.right(30)


# draw the numbers
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 190)
pen.write("12", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(220, -30)
pen.write("3", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, -240)
pen.write("6", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(-220, -30)
pen.write("9", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(110, 150)
pen.write("1", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(-100, 150)
pen.write("11", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(180, 80)
pen.write("2", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(-170, 80)
pen.write("10", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(180, -140)
pen.write("4", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(-180, -140)
pen.write("8", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(110, -210)
pen.write("5", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(-110, -210)
pen.write("7", align="center", font=("Courier", 50, "normal"))

clock = turtle.Turtle()


def draw_clock(hour, minute, second, pen):
    hands = [("black", 90, 12), ("black", 160, 60), ("black", 120, 60)]
    time_set = (hour, minute, second)
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    pen.hideturtle()
    for x in hands:
        time_part = time_set[hands.index(x)]
        angle = (time_part/x[2])*360
        pen.penup()
        pen.pensize(10)
        pen.goto(0, 0)
        pen.color(x[0])
        pen.setheading(90)
        pen.right(angle)
        pen.pendown()
        pen.forward(x[1])
        pen.penup()


while True:
    hour = int(time.strftime("%I"))
    minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    second = int(time.strftime("%S"))

    draw_clock(hour, minute, second, pen)
    window.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    clock.clear()
```

---

example image:

[image]

Comment: "The form will not post unless I add more words, so I am willing up this space" -- not really the spirit of the restriction. You haven't provided many details about your debugging attempts. Where did you move the functions around to exactly? What did you observe?

Answer (score 1):

The drawing issue is that you created, and clear, the turtle `clock` but accidentally passed the turtle `pen` to `draw_clock()` so you were clearing the wrong turtle.

There is also a logic problem with your code as the angles of the hands of a clock are not independent.  You can't just point the hour hand to '3' until it's four o'clock and then move it to '4'.  It's position between '3' and '4' depends on the minue.  Ditto for minute depending on second.

Below is a rework of your code that addresses both of the above issues as well as weeds out a lot of the needless code redundancy.  (How many times do you need to hide the same turtle?  Fifteen apparently.)

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from time import strftime, sleep

FONT = ('Courier', 50, 'normal')
HANDS = [('black', 160, 60), ('black', 120, 60), ('black', 90, 12)]

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('beige')
screen.tracer(0)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.pensize(10)

# Draw the clock
pen.setheading(90)
pen.penup()
pen.setx(280)
pen.pendown()
pen.fillcolor('white')

pen.begin_fill()
pen.circle(280)
pen.end_fill()

# draw the minute hashes
pen.color('black')
pen.pensize(2)

for _ in range(60):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.forward(250)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.forward(20)
    pen.right(6)

# Draw the hour hashes
pen.pensize(5)

for _ in range(12):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 0)
    pen.forward(240)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.forward(30)
    pen.penup()
    pen.right(30)

# Draw the numbers
pen.goto(0, 190)
pen.write("12", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(220, -30)
pen.write("3", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(0, -240)
pen.write("6", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(-220, -30)
pen.write("9", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(110, 150)
pen.write("1", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(-100, 150)
pen.write("11", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(180, 80)
pen.write("2", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(-170, 80)
pen.write("10", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(180, -140)
pen.write("4", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(-180, -140)
pen.write("8", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(110, -210)
pen.write("5", align='center', font=FONT)
pen.goto(-110, -210)
pen.write("7", align='center', font=FONT)

clock = Turtle()

def draw_clock(hour, minute, second, pen):

    time_set = (second, minute, hour)

    pen.pensize(10)

    previous_angle = 0

    for i, (color, length, divisions) in enumerate(HANDS):
        time_part = time_set[i]
        angle = time_part * (360 / divisions) + previous_angle / 12
        pen.penup()
        pen.goto(0, 0)
        pen.color(color)
        pen.setheading(90)
        pen.right(angle)
        pen.pendown()
        pen.forward(length)

        previous_angle = angle

while True:
    hour = int(strftime("%I"))
    minute = int(strftime("%M"))
    second = int(strftime("%S"))

    clock.clear()
    draw_clock(hour, minute, second, clock)
    screen.update()
    sleep(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could undo the last few turtle actions to 'undraw' the hands after sleeping:

```
while True:
    hour = int(time.strftime("%I"))
    minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    second = int(time.strftime("%S"))

    draw_clock(hour, minute, second, pen)
    window.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    for _ in range(24):pen.undo()  # guesstimated the number of undos
```